# Unable to connect to MongoDB with error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Visual Studio Code.

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB database to store values, but then I'm getting an error: UnHandledPromiseRejection

> error =>  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.234.193.81:27017

This the code that I used to connect to MongoDB:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://node-shop:'+ process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW +'@node-rest-shop-shard-00-00-ylfa8.mongodb.net:27017,node-rest-shop-shard-00-01-ylfa8.mongodb.net:27017,node-rest-shop-shard-00-02-ylfa8.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=node-rest-shop-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true', {
    useNewUrlParser: true 
});
```

Comment: Likely two problems, your mongodb url is incorrect (why you're not connecting), and `mongoose.connect(..).catch((err) => console.log(err))` will catch your promise rejection.

Answer (score 0):

The way you used returns a promise. You have to handle it with a callback. If you have not then use the second way as below. Async/Await principal will work

```
1.
    mongoose.connect(uri, options, function(error) {
      // Check error in initial connection. There is no 2nd param to the callback.
    });

2.  
    // Or using promises
    mongoose.connect(uri, options).then(
      () => { /** ready to use. The `mongoose.connect()` promise resolves to undefined. */ },
      err => { /** handle initial connection error */ }
    );
```